# How to Get Google Blogger Access Token In Windows Phone 8.1 Universal Apps

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I Used The Below code to get access Token But it Throws Method is not implemented. How to get Access token Please help me to get access token in windows phone 8.1 Universal Apps

```
StringBuilder authLink = new StringBuilder();

            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            authLink.AppendFormat("code={0}", "code");
            authLink.AppendFormat("&client_id={0}", "xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com");
            authLink.AppendFormat("&client_secret={0}", "xxxxxxxxxx");
            authLink.AppendFormat("&redirect_uri={0}", "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob");
            authLink.Append("&grant_type=authorization_code");
            UTF8Encoding utfenc = new UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] bytes = utfenc.GetBytes(authLink.ToString());
            Stream os = null;

            try // send the post
            {
                 // Count bytes to send
                os =await webRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync();
                os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);        // Send it
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
            }
            try // get the response
            {
                HttpWebResponse webResponse =(HttpWebResponse)await webRequest.GetResponseAsync();
                if (webResponse == null) 
                {

                }
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
                String Text = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
                //MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd().Trim());
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check its official APi document, search "Google Blogger API" for details.

I just glanced at the document about authorizing requests and identifying your application, it also use OAuth2.0 protocol, so you need to use the WebAuthenticationBroker class to connect to OAuth provider.

See this sample to get started: [https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/)